# AR Foundation face mesh for creating custom assets

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I'm looking for either a 3D model or an image file over which I can apply my own custom graphical elements, such as eyeliner or lipstick.

In the [ARCore docs](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/developer-guides/creating-assets-for-augmented-faces), the solution to this issue is very well described. You can get either an FBX file or a PSD template, over which you place your own elements.

From what I can tell, the principle of ARCore and ARKit are very much the same - there's a standard face mesh which gets contorted to the shape of a detected face, however, I'm unable to find any such materials using Google.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same face model and use slightly larger copies of it for the makeup. No one is going to get close enough to see how thick its caked on, because all the polys would start disappearing anyway...

Comment: And which assumption to you presume is incorrect? I suggested an alternate way where you don't have to mess with the base but just copies. Wonder how Snapchat supports so many using only javascript...

Comment: So the description of the AR Foundation is a bit misleading - you have a separate ARCore face mesh and ARkit face mesh and you need to apply textures for both of those models. The model for ARKit you can actually find here -> https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/5342449cea/TrackingAndVisualizingFaces.zip

Now, about your incorrect assumption - how do you figure I match up these two together? https://github.com/ljmatan/arkit/blob/main/copy.png

Comment: Sorry, the terms base and foundation also apply to makeup, so I was thinking the undermost face would be a more uniform color and each offset a copy of it, having the additional makeup, rather than trying to mash-it-up into a texture. AR core, kit, and snaplens API's seem to be intended for prerendered masks...

Comment: No worries I appreciate your assistance but I also think it's important to clarify for any potential future viewers.

Comment: FYI: Google has something similar on their blog here, but they pass through most of the face untouched: https://www.blog.google/products/shopping/shopping-beauty-product-try-it-google/ This is probably the last thing I'm going to post on Stack Overflow comments because their stupid brownie-points dropped way down almost below 50 with no explanation. It seems not worth the effort answering questions with such a random system...